# Why did I get so many syntax errors with this code?

Tags: c

This is my *rect.h* code. The error code is *C2143, syntax error*.

```
#pragma once
void draw_rect(const RECT*);
double calc_area(const RECT*);
void move_rect(RECT*, int, int);

struct rect {
    int x, y, w, h;
};

typedef struct rect RECT
```

Comment: The last line is missing a semicolon, and should be before the first use of RECT.

Comment: What compiler? Visual Studio's? (not to be confused with [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reference `RECT` before declaring it. Move the `typedef` to the top.

```c
typedef struct rect RECT;

void draw_rect(const RECT*);
double calc_area(const RECT*);
void move_rect(RECT*, int, int);

struct rect {
    int x, y, w, h;
};
```

You are now referring a struct type before declaring it, but you're allowed to do that in this fashion.

That said, you could avoid that "special" situation by moving the `struct rect` declaration too.

```c
struct rect {
    int x, y, w, h;
};

typedef struct rect RECT;

void draw_rect(const RECT*);
double calc_area(const RECT*);
void move_rect(RECT*, int, int);
```